# C# application says "No" when executed

Tags: c#, .net, dll, console-application, executable

I have developed a small-ish C# console application (TextMatcher.exe) on my local development machine and now need to deploy it to the live environment.  It references another class library which I developed which has generic functions, which I intend to use and improve in future console applications.

Ultimately this specific application will be executed from within an SSIS package, but for now I'm just trying to run it from `cmd`.

**I kid you not** that this is the actual output from the program:

```
E:/TextMatcher>TextMatcher.exe
No

E:/TextMatcher>
```

The [computer literally says "No"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_says_no#Personality) and gives no further information. I have not included, anywhere in the program, to output the word "No", on any failure or otherwise.

Of course, it runs fine locally.  I made sure I included the dll of the utility class library too.  I have read other questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939438), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676577)) about how to deploy console apps correctly, and have followed the advice.

NB: This is also proving to be quite hard to Google because of the use of the word "No" being fundamental to the problem...

**EDIT - It seems to be working now...** I simply copied over the files again from my local machine to the remote machine... I am trying to get it to break again so that I can figure out what on Earth happened, and until I do, I will not accept an answer so that people could maybe shed some more light onto it.  Either way it is quite baffling.

Comment: Please include some of your code, I'm dying to see this.

Comment: »No« is not a standard message from anything in the system or framework (unless you have an embedded Prolog, but then it'd be »No.«). So you should perhaps look under what circumstances the code of the program prints »No«.

Comment: Something must have written the word No on either the output or error. To find out where you could redirect them to you're own TextWriter class and Write the stacktrace out if it tries to write out No.

Comment: The code is nothing special! I can't include too much as it's on a restricted network. But even if I put in a `writeline` as the first executable line, it still doesn't reach it

Comment: Do you use any DLL's outside of the one you wrote and the standard .Net ones?

Comment: Do you have the Dot net framework installed on the deployment machine? C# applications behave sometimes very strange when you do not meet the prerequisits

Comment: Debug the code and find the line (be it directly or the library call that does it) that prints "No" and exits (might be separate lines).

Comment: *"But even if I put in a writeline as the first executable line, it still doesn't reach i"* then it's an issue with the shell, not C#.  Run a virus scanner maybe?  What shell are you using?  cmd?  powershell?  some custom shell your company uses?

Comment: @TimS. I **guarantee** that I have not included any line in the program that outputs 'No' and then quits. Joey mentioned in his answer that there is a potential Framework issue, I think that is more likely

Comment: .Net is definitely installed.  @Servy - I am using `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @a12jun - You're running it on some remote machine, yes? (`it runs fine locally`) Possibly the "No" is a result of some security restrictions in place. Such as being unable to run random programs from the command line, as Servy alludes.

Comment: @Esotoric Yes, but I'm remoting into the server using PROXY which is remote control rather than remote session

Comment: @all please see edit in question

Comment: seems that you deployed some wrong version of your Dll in the first place, rebuilt your project (replacing your class library) and then magically everything runs fine. do you still have the broken version? please have a look at my answer.

Comment: @MareInfinitus - I already upvoted your answer and was playing around with the bits you mentioned.  I got to the dll part and then redeployed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you have installed the necessary Framework components,
i.e. the suiting Dot net framework. Application with 4.0 and installed 3.5
can cause very strange behaviour.

Try writing a very simple window application and start it on the deployment machine 
(this will give you probably more help what is missing).

Check whether the needed Dlls (that you developed, e.g. your class library) are reachable for the console application. And check whether the right version of your Dll is matched!

Check the plattform settings in your console application. Do they match with
the machine where you want to run your application? (win64 and win32 mismatch)

If all of those do not help, try inspecting your executable on the deployment machine
for example with depends.net, checkasm, or similar.

Comment: Thanks, yes it could also just be a the exe file corrupted during copying

Comment: Could be the case, of course. Most important that everything works correctly now.

Answer (score 3):

There's a chance that someone has modified the Image File Execution Options registry setting on the server to [launch a debugger automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed.aspx).

In short, examine the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\currentversion\image file execution options` and see if there's an entry that matches the name of your executable.

Comment: (Note: The program launched doesn't have to actually be a debugger)

Answer (score 0):

Does your production environment have [AppLocker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723678%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) running? I don't know if its output can be customized to output "No" on a command line. Applocker comes to my mind because you can use it to restrict a system to run only signed executables. If your Textmatcher executable is unsigned, it may get shut down immediately. If you have the ability, I'd be curious to see if signing your binary changes the behavior.